# Проблема с fullpage.js на Mac

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fullpage

При использовании библиотеки fullpage.js(https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#page1) на Mac OS сильно лагает при скролле, но на Windows всё норм. У кого-нибудь была такая проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в определенной версии MacOS. Обновление системы решило проблему.